# Find column number of last match in a row in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

In this table it's easy to find that column E is the first match for the value 3.

How do I find the column of the last match of 3 which will be column I

```
A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J   K   L
6   6   9   9   3   3   2   2   3   1   1   1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this formula**

```
=ArrayFormula(Substitute(Address(1,MAX(IF(REGEXMATCH(A1:L1,3&"")<>TRUE,,COLUMN(A1:L1))),4),"1",""))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(ADDRESS(2, XMATCH(3, A2:P2,, -1), 4), 2, )
```

[image]

---

```
=ADDRESS(2, XMATCH(3, A2:P2,, -1), 4)
```

[image]

---

```
=XLOOKUP(3, A2:P2, A1:P1,,, -1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`XMATCH` has a [reverse search feature](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12406049). Set `search_mode` top `-1` to activate:

```
=INDEX(1:1,XMATCH(3,2:2,,-1))
```

| (A1)A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I | J | K | L |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 6 | 9 | 9 | 3 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

#### Result:

```
I
```